# principle of QEMU CPU emulation

Tags: linux, qemu, emulation

In QEMU, an operating system can run above software emulated CPU.
**How can be a CPU emulated by software?**
I want to know about detail.

**If CPU is emulated by software does registers are emulated with host system memory?**

Let say there is ARM assembly code

```
LDRB r0, [r1], #1
```

**How can this be emulated in x86 environment?**

My guess is that emulating software keeps memory mapping space for `r0` (4 bytes), `r1` (4 bytes) and then updates the register value for corresponding memory location... Am I wrong?

Comment: I dont think the above is a fair comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please see [this file](http://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=blob;f=target-arm/cpu.h;h=ffddfcbc0d1d18b5b23d92dabde8fda492246cc5;hb=HEAD) for the C-level modelling of the state of an ARM CPU as done by QEMU.

It's pretty straight-forward, and (of course) as you suspect the registers (and all other state) are modelled as C variables.

The core structure begins:

```
typedef struct CPUARMState {
    /* Regs for current mode.  */
    uint32_t regs[16];
   /* Frequently accessed CPSR bits are stored separately for efficiency.
      This contains all the other bits.  Use cpsr_{read,write} to access
      the whole CPSR.  */
   uint32_t uncached_cpsr;
   uint32_t spsr;
```